# PyCharm can't connect to MySQLDatabase, using peewee

Tags: mysql, peewee

My english is not good but I will try to explain my problem. I'm learning peewee and I can't make the connection between mysql and pycharm. This is my code:

```
from peewee import *
db = MySQLDatabase("test", host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", passwd="password")
db.connect()
```

And it throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a database driver:

```
$ pip install pymysql
```